# I am the owner of the sharepoint site and I am approving the access requests but users not able to access the site

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, office-365

I am the owner of a SharePoint site and I am approving the access requests but users are unable to access the site.

Users are unable to access the SharePoint site even after approving the access request.

Comment: Please provide more detail e.g. errors that the users are experiencing etc

Answer (score 0):

1.Clear the browser cache, then have a test.

2.Try to access through InPrivate browser.

3.Check Whether the home page has the unique permission.